# Serialize into XML a list with multiple types without root element name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to serialize my object below but I cannot serialize it without root name of list. Hub, Switch and Device are derived type from AbstractNode.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Roothub")]
public class RootHub
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Hub), ElementName = "Hub20")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Switch), ElementName = "Switch")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Device), ElementName = "Device")]
    public List<AbstractNode> DevicesList { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(Hub))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Device))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Switch))]

public abstract class AbstractNode
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
<RootHub>
   <DevicesList>
      <Hub20 Tag="HUB1" VidPid="VID_0000&amp;PID_0000"/>
      <Switch Tag="SWITCH1" />
      <Device Tag="MOUSE" VidPid="VID_0000&amp;PID_0000"/>
   </DevicesList>
</RootHub>
```

But what I need is this:

```
<RootHub>
   <Hub20 Tag="HUB1" VidPid="VID_0000&amp;PID_0000"/>
   <Switch Tag="SWITCH1" />
   <Device Tag="MOUSE" VidPid="VID_0000&amp;PID_0000"/>
</RootHub>
```

I've already tried solution from this question [Getting rid of an array name in C# XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650831/getting-rid-of-an-array-name-in-c-sharp-xml-serialization) but it won't work because it's not possible to mix XmlArrayItem with XmlElement attributes. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: Can number of Device can be more than one?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple Hub20, Switches, Devices.

Comment: What does your DevicesList class look like?

Comment: It's not a class, its just list of AbstractNode objects. Each device is dervied from that class.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean AbstractNode class

Comment: I've edited my question and added AbstractNode class definition

Comment: I am late, answer is correct :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `XmlElement` attribute instead of `XmlArrayItem`, it will give you the output you want.

```
[XmlElement(typeof(Hub), ElementName = "Hub20")]
[XmlElement(typeof(Switch), ElementName = "Switch")]
[XmlElement(typeof(Device), ElementName = "Device")]
public List<AbstractNode> DevicesList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Wow thank man. I can't believe in such easy solution. I've lost countless time trying to find way, including custom serialization using IXmlSerializable without any results...

Comment: What about using class instead of List? Like Money Price {get; set;}. Money has Amount and Currency properties. Can we serialize an object like this way? It does not work in same way. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @ahmet your question doesn't seem at all related to the OP's question. You should post a new question, not a comment.