# How to rename the serialization root object name in a class?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

(First, feel free to edit my title, I really don't find a better one for my problem)

I got my root class:

```
[XmlRoot("ProductList")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement("Property1")]
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Property2")]
    public Property2 property2 { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Property3Array")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Property3ArrayItem")]

    public List<Property3> property3{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm serializing the List of `Products` like this:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var products = _productionService.GetAllProducts();

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("products.xml"))
    {
        xs.Serialize(sw, products);
    }

}
```

The serialization is working properly BUT, in my `products.xml` file, the root node is:

```
<ArrayOfProduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    ...
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

But I want the root element of the list to be named *ProductList*

I tried with `[XmlRoot("ProductList")]` But that doesn't work.

So, how can I rename the name of the root xml object of a `List<Class>` ?

Comment: *"But I want the root element of the list to be named `ProductList`"* - then don't serialize `Product[]`, but create a holder type (name it... `ProductList`).

Comment: @Sinatr I really should get some rest because I didn't even thought of that... Yep, you're right. But for the sake of the question, is this possible to rename to root element with some attribute ? Like for example `[XmlRoot("ProductList")]`. And, small remark, after the serialization, the root object is named `ArrayOf...`. How to get rid of this ?

Comment: You should already been able to [achieve that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3650831/1997232) with `XmlElementAttribute`.

Comment: Sadly, the `XmlElementAttribute` cannot decore a class

Comment: Hmm? I have you seen the linked question? Put array into `ProductList` class property and add attribute to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts an `XmlRootAttribute`.

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("ProductList"));
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ouvwg) for a working demo.